# combining 2 sas dataset

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to combine two datasets t1 and t2:

dataset 1 (one variable X)

```
 X
 1
 2
 3 
 4
```

dataset 2 (one variable Y)

```
 Y
 A
 B
 C
```

into one new dataset
dataset1+2 t3

```
 X  Y
 1  A
 1  B
 1  C
 2  A
 2  B
 2  C
 3  A
 3  B
 3  C
 4  A
 4  B
 4  C
```

As you can see, I have no common variables, I tried different flavours of set and merge combination

```
data t3 ; merge t1 t2 ; run ;
data t3 ; set t1 ; set t2 ; run ;
data t3 ; set t1 ; if _n_  then set t2 ; run ;
data t3 ; set t1 t2  ; run ;
```

any help (SAS or SQL) much appreciated

Regards

SW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work and produce the expected results, basically you are looking at a Cartesian product in SAS,

```
proc sql;
  select t1.*,t2.*
  from t1 ,t2
  ;
quit;
```

[Output of above Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXXaE.png)

Comment: Thank you. Straight and simple. It worked like a charm !

Comment: My pleasure, Can you please mark the answer useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab1(X INT);

CREATE TABLE #tab2(Y NVARCHAR(12));

INSERT INTO #tab1
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);

INSERT INTO #tab2
VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C');

SELECT X, Y
FROM #tab1
CROSS JOIN #tab2
ORDER BY X, Y;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377740)**</kbd>

Comment: @Utsav Actually SEDE is for querying SE database (see tables on sidebar) but we can create temp table and temp variable so why not use it here :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on DB so this should work in most

```
 select a.X,b.Y from 
 dataset1 a , dataset2 b
 where 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (X int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (X)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4)
;

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE 
    (Y varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO @Table2
    (Y)
VALUES
    ('A'),
    ('B'),
    ('C')
;
select * from @Table1 T cross apply (select * from @Table2)TT

ORDER BY t.X
```